# Optimizing the size of pie chart in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to create a pie chart of size 320 x 320 px as shown below:

[image: Pie Chart]

When a pie is selected, it should expand like this:

[image: Pie Selected]

What I have been able to achieve so far is shown below, which is obviously too far from the spirit of the design. I am not sure what levers to pull to get as close as possible to the requirements. Please see my CodeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-demo-4bzh8).

[image: Actual implementation]

The high-level requirements are:

- Chart size: 320 x 320 px
- Donut diameter: 152px
- Font family: Overpass
- Font sizes:

  - General: 12px
  - Title: 16px
  - Total count: 32px

Some questions I have:

1. How to reduce the size of the "ticks" so that the ellipsis on category labels are avoided. Or is there a way to wrap the category labels to avoid the ellipsis?
2. How to add the data value to each spending category?
3. How to add the total value in the middle?
4. How to control font sizes on each element?
5. How to grow a pie when selected?
6. How to suppress the animations on hover?

My implementation so far is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-demo-4bzh8).

**Update**

After further research and incorporating changes suggested by @Sebastian Wędzel, I have been able to bring the implementation upto the following level:

[image]

Comment: Refer this document - https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie

Comment: Thanks, @roa. After referring to the docs, I was able to figure out how to make the size of the pie bigger. However I couldn't figure out the rest of the answers. The docs are huge and I am still getting my head around them. I have updated my list of questions as well as the CodeSandbox. Any further help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you already found most of the answers to your questions. Here are my proposals for unanswered questions:

- Chart size: 320 x 320 px - you can define the `chart.width` and `chart.height`

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.width

- > How to add the total value in the middle?

You can render it as a custom text by using the SVGRenderer tool.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xbhas3g6/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#text

- > How to grow a pie when selected?

Here you probably will need to change your series type to the `variablepie` - demo: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/variable-radius-pie and implement the `point.update` on the click event to increase selected point Z value.

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.variablepie.point.events.click

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#update

Comment: Thanks for your help, @Sebastian. Yes, I was able to answer several questions by diving into the docs. A couple of questions for you: 1) Is there an advantage to using `chart.width` and `chart.height` vs my approach, i.e. setting the containing div to that size and then setting `containerProps={{ style: { width: '100%', height: '100%' } }}`? 2) For growing the pie on select, I have currently just set `allowPointSelect`. The behavior is not per design, I will see if the designers are ok with it. Otherwise I will pursue your suggestion.

Comment: I implemented the total value in the middle based on your example. It was a bit tricky to convert your example to React-based code (using `useRef` and `useEffect`) but I got it working eventually. The only issue I am seeing is that the total value is slightly to the left of the center. Is there something that I have missed?

Comment: In fact, I can now reproduce this in your example too. You can either change the number from 88 to say 100, or the label to something shorter like "$" and you will see the misalignment.

Comment: @Naresh sorry for late reply! 1) there is no special advantage of using `chart.width/height`. By default it will be calculated from your container div, more: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.height 2) In case to center this label you can do same translation as for the subtitle: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bsf0orde/